# Mindmap sibling angle in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, mindmaps

I am using the following tikz example ([original source](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/))

**MWE:**

```
% Author: Till Tantau
% Source: The PGF/TikZ manual
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Computer Science}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {%
      node[concept] {practical}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child {node[concept] {algorithms} }
      child {node[concept] {data structures} }
      child {node[concept] {pro\-gramming languages} }
      child {node[concept] {software engineer\-ing} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] {%
      node[concept] {applied}
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child {node[concept] {databases} }
      child {node[concept] {WWW} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] {node[concept] {technical} }
    child[concept color=orange] {node[concept] {theoretical} };
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Where each child is spread 60 degrees apart. I presume you control this spacing with `sibling angle=60` (got the idea from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/scientific-interactions/)), but I can't use it to change the spacing. Could someone modify the MWE to illustrate how to use it. I would very much appreciate it if you could use a different angle for each branch (including the main branch). Thank you.

**EDIT:**
There seems to be some confusion as people think I want to space things out randomly. What I want is this instead, if a node has two children, I want to define the spacing to be 180 degrees, if it has 3 children, I want the spacing to be 120 degrees, 4 children, 90 degrees, 5 children 72 degrees and so on. As is, I must have 6 children for it to not look weird.

Comment: Within the example that you suggested: [Scientific interactions](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/scientific-interactions/), syntax `child [grow=-10, level distance=160]` is used to place child at certain angle and distance from its parent concept. Is this what you want?

Comment: You can also give node position:     child[concept color=orange ] {node[concept] at (-3,-2) {theoretical} };

Comment: The original source for your example is `pgfmanual`. There you find a comment which says `note that 'sibling angle' can only be defined in 'level 1 concept/.append style={}'`.

Comment: @Ignasi sadly I am not sure what that means

Comment: Means that `sibling angle` has to be defined for every level, it's not possible to apply it to a particular concept. If you want to apply diferent angles to every concept whithin a certain level, you must use `grow` or `at` syntax.

Comment: @Ignasi I clarified the question

Comment: Are you sure about the angles? From where do you measure? A child can possibly overlap its grandparent. Without taking a look into the manual if something like this exist, I believe this needs an own growth function (for automatic calculation of the angles).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The style `set angles for level` is used to append the correct `sibling distance` for level `#1`.

It can either used inside the `level` style or possibly in a `.list`ed option.

Usage should vary depending on the use-case in a real document. It may preferable to append `set angles for level` to `grow cyclic` or create a custom `special grow cyclic` that used this solution.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,graphs}
\tikzset{
  set angles for level/.style={level #1/.append style={sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren}},
  level/.append style={set angles for level=#1}% solution 1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[
    mindmap,
    concept color=black,
    text=white,
    grow cyclic,
    nodes=concept,
%    set angles for level/.list={1,...,4}% solution 2
  ]
  node {Computer Science} 
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {%
      node {practical}
      child {node {algorithms} }
      child {node {data structures} }
      child {node {pro\-gramming languages} }
      child {node {software engineer\-ing} }
      child {node {and a fifth}}
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] { node[concept] {applied}
      child {node {databases} }
      child {node {WWW} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] {node {technical} }
    child[concept color=orange] {node {theoretical} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]